# How to compute a floating point modulo in Racket? [flmod]

Tags: racket

The standard `modulo` in Racket doesn't work with floating points.

How do I compute modulo with non-integer arguments (`flmod`)?

Comment: This was meant to be a community wiki - but I can't find where to convert it from a question to a community wiki.

Answer (score 3):

In some languages the modulo operator also works for non-integer arguments.
In Racket the modulo operator is for integer arguments only,

In the case you need one that works with floating points, use
the following definition:

```
(define (flmod x m)
    (- x (* (floor (/ x m)) m))
```

There is no standard definition for such an operation (different programming
languages interprets this operation differently), so check that
the function above matches you expectations first.

Comment: This might be a good candidate to pr to become a part of Racket itself or some other library close to it.